# Resources of learning model theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation, big-list

I am an student who will take model theory in next semester. Could someone give me some advise on choosing materials of learning it? I would like to know what books are good to read and their levels. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stephen Simpson, [Model Theory](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/master.pdf) (1998).

Comment: David Marker, [Model Theory : An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=gkvogoiEnuYC&printsec=frontcover) (2002).

Comment: Alexander Prestel & Charles Delzell, [Mathematical Logic and Model Theory : A Brief Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=Rz2slFjlTE0C&printsec=frontcover) (2011).

Comment: Katrin Tent & Martin Ziegler, [A Course in Model Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=D9sClsdErEsC&pg=PA1) (2012).

Comment: See also the post : [learning model theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161924/learning-model-theory).

Answer (score 0):

Chang and Keisler is the best book in my opinion. It's slow going and comprehensive, but is an incredible text on model theory.